# Colourise CGContextRef But Preserve Alpha

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alpha, cgcontext, colorize

I have a `CGContextRef` and can draw on it and specify the alpha, and if I try and use it it works perfectly. However, I am trying to colourise it (currently either red or green), but whatever blend mode I choose, the alpha is set to `1` (because I am drawing with alpha as `1`). Drawing it the correct colour is not really a viable option, as I would like to be able to colour `UIImage`s loaded from the filesystem as well, so how should I achieve this?

Edit: Example code (width and height are predefined floats, points is an array of CGPoints all of which lie inside the context and color is a UIColor with an opacity of 100%) -

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width,height));

CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height));
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, lineWidth);

CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, points[0].x, points[0].y);
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, points[i].x, points[i].y);
}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, points[0].x, points[0].y); // Encloses shape

CGContextDrawPath(contextRef, kCGPathFillStroke);

[color setFill];

CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);
CGContextSetBlendMode(contextRef, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextAddRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height));
CGContextDrawPath(contextRef, kCGPathFill);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
jrtc27

Comment: Could you give us some example code so we can better look at your problem?

Comment: Alright this helps. I'm trying to grasp to way you think so please tell me if I'm correct.
From what I see here is you are trying to draw a white rect with a black border without transparancy. Then your doing an unknown function [color setFill]; which I don't know what it does (even though the names speak for themselves, you might wanna give us that piece of info too). Then you are are drawing another path with same dimension on top of the prior rect. Then you want to take the drawing and store it in that image var.

Comment: Now some clearification: kCGBlendModeMultiply multiplies the source image samples with the background image samples. This results in colors that are at least as dark as either of the two contributing sample colors. So you might want to use another anyway. Try setting it to normal and post results.
Also: if you have problems with the alpha, try setting it manually to the context using the function: 
CGContextSetAlpha (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat alpha
);

Try it and post results here.

Comment: I want the White quad an black border to have alpha 1 and the background to have alpha 0 - I achieve this. However I am trying to take this image and apply a colour whilst not changing the alpha of the context. Should I still try your suggestion? BTW [color setFill] makes a UIColor be the fill colour for the current context.

Comment: i'm not very well understand you, but maybe it helpful CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
 and one this http://www.developers-life.com/color-picker-for-ios.html - example, getting color from image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I needed a `CGContextClipToMask`. This meant my code required the following:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(contextRef, 0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(contextRef, 1.0, -1.0);
```

to convert the coordinates and then

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
CGContextClipToMask(contextRef, rect, UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage);
```

to fix it.